# How to do a for-each in ItemStyle.xsl

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part

I'm trying to pull in custom columns from a SP list, and it works fine, but now I have to figure out how to do a for-each instead since it needs to pull in all items not just one.

Here's where I am so far:

```
<xsl:template name="forSale" match="Row[@Style='forSale']" mode="itemstyle">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="banner-slide">
            <ul class="bjqs">
                <li><a href="{@FileURL}" />'><img src="{@ThumbnailURL}" title="{@Caption}" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

The `<li>` part is the one I need to do a for-each on.  Any ideas how to accomplish this?

**EDIT:** 
How about this instead?

SharePoint's ItemStyle template pulls in each row from a list automatically, so how would I pull this piece before the ItemStyle

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div id="banner-slide">
            <ul class="bjqs">
```

And this piece of code after ItemStyle?

```
</ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is how my ItemStyle would look then:

```
<xsl:template name="forSale" match="Row[@Style='forSale']" mode="itemstyle">
    <li><a href="{@FileURL}" />'><img src="{@ThumbnailURL}" title="{@Caption}" /></a></li>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do it by modifying the ContentQueryMain.xsl file to insert non-repeating markup before and after content query as shown here.

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/wrapping-contents-content-query-web-part-additional-markup/

Answer (score 4):

See if this helps:

```
                  <xsl:for-each select="rows\row">
                    <li>
                      <a>
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                          <xsl:value-of select="{@FileURL}" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="src">
                          <xsl:value-of select="{@ThumbnailURL}" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="title">
                          <xsl:value-of select="{@Caption}" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </xsl:for-each>
```

Please correct the "Rows\Row" as I'm not exactly sure about the list schema.

Comment: Nope that doesn't work either.  I had to put src and title within `img` tag, but it still didn't work.  I changed my original post to maybe make it easier.

Answer (score 1):

If your match is correct, do something of the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="forSale">
  <li>
    <a href="<xsl:value-of select='FileURL' />">
       <img src="<xsl:value-of select='ThumbnailURL' />" 
            title="<xsl:value-of select='Caption' />" />
    </a>
  </li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

For more reference, take a look at [MSDN <xsl:for-each> Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256166.aspx)

Comment: What happens when I do this is that each item gets its own `<div class="wrapper">` and it's own `ul`.  In other words, that whole code is repeated, whereas I only need the `<li>` piece to repeat.

Comment: @zen Have you tried to place the foreach statement just including the <li></li> tags, since that's what you want to have repeated?

Comment: @zen I need to see the source of FileURL, ThumbnailURL and Caption to know what to select from in my for-each statement...

Comment: I added the XML output of that entire SharePoint list.  Does that help?